# Didn't get "On The Road" Hat or "Bugdroid" Hat

Tags: support, winter-bash-2014

Yesterday evening, I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27530013/1777090) question from my android device using [Android app SoClient](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sudosaints.stackoverflow&hl=en)

I didn't get "On The Road" hat or "BugDroid" Hat.

Is there any other thing which plays role here?

Comment: Well, I agree that for those who don't know Stack Exchange has official apps it's not trivial and might look like the hats are given for using any app that is using the API. Might be worth to ask a feature request to change the hats description, making it clear they mean the official SE app.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That app isn't even using the API! It's just a a wrapper around a web-view showing the mobile site.

Comment: @Caleb oh wow... so it should be common sense there's no hat for this. Oh well! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is not the official Stack Exchange app and does not count towards the hats.

[Here is the official Stack Exchange app on Google Play.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin&hl=en)

Comment: Okay.. thanks. Was in the process of installing after posting question.. :-)